# Sign of first eigenvalue of conformal Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conformal-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be some manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$. The conformal Laplacian is given by
$L=-4 \frac{n-1}{n-2} \Delta+ R$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature of $M$ and $\Delta= -\operatorname{div}\circ \operatorname{grad}$.

> Now assume that $g$ is a Riemannian metric, $M$ is orientable, compact and has no boundary.
>   Show that the sign of the first eigenvalue of $L$ is a conformal invariant.

Why is that so?
I was able to show some transformation law for $L$.
Namely, if $\tilde{g}=v^{4/(n-2)}g$, then for some function $\varphi >0$ we have
$L(\varphi)=v^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}} \tilde{L} (v^{-1} \varphi)$.
(Here $\tilde{L}$ is the conformal Laplacian with respect to the metric $\tilde{g}$) I originaly hoped I could conclude something similar to:

$(\varphi, \lambda)$ eigenpair for $L$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(v^{-1} \varphi, \lambda \cdot \max v)$ eigenpair for $\tilde{L}$.

However I did not have any luck with that so far.
(And obviously the above line is NOT true. I just wanted to give an impression what kind of statement I was looking for)

How could I go about this exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the $L^2$ pairing satisfies

$$ \langle L(\phi),\phi\rangle_g = \int L(\phi)\phi \mathrm{d}v_g = \int \tilde{L}(\nu^{-1} \phi) \nu^{-1} \phi \nu^{\frac{2n}{n-2}} \mathrm{d}v_g = \int\tilde{L}(\nu^{-1}\phi) \nu^{-1}\phi \mathrm{d}v_{\tilde{g}} = \langle \tilde{L}(\nu^{-1}\phi) , \nu^{-1}\phi\rangle_{\tilde{g}}$$

1. The first eigenvalue of $L$ is negative if and only if there exists $\phi$ such that $\langle L(\phi),\phi\rangle < 0$. But then $\nu^{-1}\phi$ is such that $\langle \tilde{L}(\nu^{-1}\phi),\nu^{-1}\phi\rangle_{\tilde{g}}< 0$, showing that the first eigenvalue of $\tilde{L}$ is negative.
2. The first eigenvalue of $L$ is nonnegative if and only if $\forall \phi, \langle L(\phi),\phi\rangle_g \geq 0$. Given the equation above we see that this is also conformally invariant.
3. Furthermore, the first eigenvalue of $L$ is zero if and only if additionally there exists $\phi$ such that $L(\phi) = 0$. But then $\tilde{L}(\nu^{-1}\phi) = 0$ showing that the first eigenvalue of $\tilde{L}$ is also zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I appreciate you took the time. Looks good, I have a small question though: You used $\nu ^{\frac{2n}{n-2}} dv_g = dv_{\tilde{g}}$. Why is that so? Wouldn't it be $\nu^{\frac{4}{n-2}} dv_g=dv_{\tilde{g}}$?

Comment: The metric scales like length squared. The volume scales like length to the power $n$. So if you have a conformal factor $\phi$, the volume changes correspondingly by $\phi^{n/2}$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for reminding me of that. Also thanks for explaining it in such simple terms.